# filter out rows from data frame based on multiple string matching conditions in R

Tags: r, string-matching

I am reading external data using `read.table()` in R like:

```
student_record <- read.table("Address of data",fill = TRUE,col.names=c("student_id","name"))
```

Student id is a 20 character long string of the format say `STU01000001010001001` and I want to keep rows where student id satisfy following conditions:

```
   ( 0 – 2 = STU) AND
(5 – 9  != 11111) AND
(10 – 11 != (00 or 10)) AND
(12 – 17  != 111111) AND
(18-19 = 04)
```

Here `0`,`2` and so on represent index of character in student id. How can I filter out records using such filter conditions?

I executed this after `read.table()` to filter:

```
stu_record <- student_record[grepl("^STU.{2}(?!11111).(?!(00|10)).(?!111111).04", student_record[,1], perl=T),]
```

but the output doesn't seems to come correct because everything gets filtered out and I get an empty frame

When I executed this:

```
stu_record <- student_record[grepl("^STU.{2}(?!11111).(?!(00|10)).(?!111111)04", student_record[,1], perl=T),]
```

then I see records but they don't seems to be correct as I can see records like `STU13120600500000002` which should not come as last two index should be `04`

**UPDATE:** few rows that I see after executing above command are(The ids dont get filtered correctly as las two digits should be `04` but I see `01`):

```
       student_id         Name    
  "STU01115000000000001"  "A"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "B"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "C"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "D"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "E"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "F"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "G"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "H"   
  "STU01115000000000001"  "I"
```

while some of the ids which should have been there but got filtered out are:

```
      "STU01155000000000004"  "F"   
      "STU01135000000000004"  "G"   
      "STU01145000000000004"  "H"   
      "STU01125000000000004"  "I"
```

**NOTE:** There are certain index in string for which there is no condition like for index `3` and `4` there is no filtering condition so they can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  I made up a test string.

```
string <- c("STU0100010", "STU0100010", "STU0300010", "STU0100090")

grepl("^STU(?!01).*(?!01|90)$", string, perl = T)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The grep function looks for strings in the vector that start with STU, but are not followed by 01 (using a negative lookahead assertion) and there is not an 01 or 90 at the end (another negative lookahead and the end of string anchor).

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr function :

```
# example data
df <- 
data.frame(
student_id=c('STUx1000xx','STU00110xx','STU01008bb','STU01090aa'),
name=c('A','B','C','D'),stringsAsFactors=F)

# > df
#   student_id name
# 1 STUx1000xx    A
# 2 STU00110xx    B
# 3 STU01008bb    C
# 4 STU01090aa    D

# create filter using substr function
condition <- substr(df$student_id,1,3) == 'STU' &
             substr(df$student_id,5,6) != '01' &
             substr(df$student_id,7,8) != '01' &
             substr(df$student_id,7,8) != '90' 

filtered <- df[condition,]

# > filtered
#   student_id name
# 1 STUx1000xx    A
# 3 STU01008bb    C
```

EDIT :

the new condition should be :

```
condition <- substr(df$student_id,1,3) == 'STU' &
             substr(df$student_id,6,10) != '11111' &
             substr(df$student_id,11,12) != '00' &
             substr(df$student_id,11,12) != '10' &
             substr(df$student_id,13,18) != '111111' &
             substr(df$student_id,19,20) == '04'
```

Comment: There is some modification in the post above regarding string length and conditions. I tried your way for these new conditions but they seems to return an empty frame(delete all records). I had executed `condition <- substr(student_record$student_id,1,3) == 'STU' & substr(student_record$student_id,6,10) != '11111' & substr(student_record$student_id,11,12) != '00' & substr(student_record$student_id,11,12) == '10' &
substr(student_record$student_id,13,18) == '111111' & substr(data_emp_mat$series_id,19,20) == '04' `

Comment: @user2966197: please modify your original post and add a small (say 10 rows) example of your data.frame and tell what's your expected result and what you actually get...

Comment: I added some data that I am getting after executing the command I have mentioned in main post

Comment: @user2966197: mmh... maybe I wasn't clear enough... you should post some lines of your original data.frame (say 3 lines that you expect to be filtered and 3 that you expected to pass the condition) and then write your expected result of the filtering process on this sample data...

Comment: I have mentioned some data which should have been there but got filtered out.

Comment: @user2966197: the last lines cannot be included since the have '00' at indexes 10-11

Comment: Anyway, I have added the new condition, according to your edit.

Comment: It does filter out but the output is not correct. I can see records like `STU04380600000000001` which should not come after filtering as they `00` at 11-12 position and also they do not have `04` at the end. There are many records of same line

Comment: I figured out the error. The issue was that conditions for index `11-12` are `or` and not `and` conditions and you have clubbed them in an `and` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Using `df` from @digEmAll

```
df[grepl("^STU.(?!01).{2}(?!(01|90))", df[,1], perl=T),]
#    student_id name
#1 STUx1000xx    A
#3 STU01008bb    C
```

Comment: I did some modification to the post above based on your answer but the output doesn't seems to come correct.Can you take a look at it. Also instead of 10 character string I have now 20 character string.

Comment: @user2966197. In think in the newly updated `df`.  substr(df[,1], 11,12)#[1] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00".  So, it won't match with none of the elements for the third condition.